# How to change Divs CSS Background given in the attribute on page Load "jquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basically I am having this problem where I want jQuery to check the class `.js-bg` in the attribute: `"data-background"`, get the attribute and then change that divs css Background to the url given in the attribute.

HTML:

```
<div class="js-bg">
    <br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.js-bg {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

JS/jQuery (first try):

```
var item = $('.js-bg'),
    bg = item.attr('data-background');

item.css('background', 'url(' + bg + ')');
```

*The Problem here is that it takes the first Attribute and then applied that image to all of the rest Divs.*

JS/jQuery (Second try):

```
var item = $('.js-bg'),
    bg = item.attr('data-background');

item.load(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'url(' + bg + ')');
});
```

*But this doesn't work aswell, I have searched all over the internet, but couldn't find an answer.*

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to loop trough those elements and set background for each one like this:

```
$('.js-bg').each(function(){

  var bg=$(this).attr('data-background');
  $(this).css('background', 'url('+ bg +')');

});
```

Comment: jquery 1.9 > versions support data-attributes, so you can simply use .data() to get the value : $(this).data('background')

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple divs with the same class, the $('.js-bg') will take all of them and replace the background on all of them.

If you only want to change one of them, you should have a unique selector on the div you wish the background changed.

$(this) will only work if something inside that element triggers the background change.